# Multiple Labels as Training data for ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Using Keras in Python to create a CNN that pumps out the angle of rotation and zoom of an image. I am working on create the training data. I have a few questions though.

I plan on using Keras Preprocessing as the tool to manipulate before I train, but is there a way to save what angle and zoom is used so that I can use those as the trainable parameters?

If not, is there something easier to use?

Comment: I'm not sure that you're problem is well defined... For example what rotation output do you expect from you CNN when fed with the image of a soccer ball?

Comment: I have several gradients in a 64 x 64 pixel box that I am rotating and zooming in on. I would like to use ML to be able to detect the angle of rotation and the zoom applied to that image. I hope this better explains?

Comment: Thanks now it makes more sense to me. Would you add to your question some examples of these images along with your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `apply_transform` of the `ImageDataGenerator` in which you can specify the parameters of the transformation you want while for example saving these parameters in a list or another structure, using them later as features.

Comment: That is the problem I am having. I guess I am lost on what the input structure of the training and test data needs to be, so I am not sure how to save these parameters. Am I able to save everything in an npz?